# Why can't I reply emails but send new one on my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, email

I cannot reply to emails on my iPad 2, but if I compose a new one it will send it fine. This is a new problem as it was working fine before and there have been no changes.

I use a Telstra Micro SIM and an optus email address.

Comment: There have been changes, somehow, somewhere. What's happening is your incoming and outgoing settings don't match up somehow. Check your authentication settings as well.

Comment: I have checked both of them over and over.I even took screen shots to ensure it was all the same.

Comment: Have you deleted and recreated them?

Comment: yeah I cleared out all fields restarted it and re endered them.

Comment: Are you receiving an error messages when you try to send the reply? Does the problem occur on multiple email account or just this one? (try making a dummy gmail to test with...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what is happening is that you have multiple email accounts setup, and when you go to compose you are using the outgoing of account **A**, and when you reply/forward you are attempting to use the outgoing of account **B**.

So to fix, check your outgoing account settings for the account that you cannot reply emails for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually deleting an app or an account and re-downloading it / reentering your account details—with a hard restart in between—will fix such errors.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks all. I have cured the problem by deleting a Yahoo account which shared the same e mail address as BT.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  Perhaps you can explain what you did more clearly and what "BT" means.